# Unable to see retract flag for the low quality answer once answer is edited

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, retracted-flags

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515731/2063361) answer as low quality because earlier it had just a hyperlink. But later the user edited the question and provided the information. I no longer see it as a low quality answer, and want to retract the flag. But I am not able to see the retract flag option.

Below is the screenshot for flag window with *Low Quality Flag*:

[image: Low Quality Screenshot]

However with the "Not a answer" flag for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45516123/2063361) I can still see the "Retract Flag" option. Here's the screenshot:

[image: Not a answer screenshot]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is by design.

*Very low quality* flags are automatically marked as helpful when the flagged post is edited, so you don't have to retract it.

This isn't the case for *Not an Answer* flags, which stay active after an edit. Thus you may have to retract it if you think the post has been edited into a valid answer.

Comment: You are right. My flagged queue status for that answer shows as "helpful"